# Django/Python/MongoDB: How to update part of the web page/form

Tags: python, django, mongodb

I have successfully coded and launched an internal site with Python+Django+MongoDB backend. Works great! But I would like to improve the user experience. There is a form where I pull up some data from MongoDB (by aggregation, counting etc.) and show it on a table (Table1).

Now if a user clicks on a particular count on a table row I would like to send another HTTP request to add a section in the same page with more information (Table2).

Currently I am sending query with extra parameter to the same "form" element which does bring the "more information" for that table row and create the Table2 but it also sends the same MongoDB query to re-create the first table (Table1) (basically rendering the whole page). 
This part I want to avoid... I do not want to re-do the first query and would like to fill only Table2 part of the webpage.

I know it can be done in Angular - I worked very briefly with Angular where I was calling REST API to connect to MSSQL server and that brings the JSON result payload and then I was using Javascript/Angular to fill certain parts of the website as needed without rendering the whole page. However in that project I was not involved in providing the Rest API service - somebody else was doing that and I was just a consumer of the Rest API service.

Now that I own the whole E2E, I do like to know....

1) How to create a REST API service which can connect to MongoDB and bring back a JSON result

2)  How to use that REST API service in my Django forms. This is where I do not want to use Angular (yet) and would like to go without Angular if possible.

I tried some JsonResponse from regular django view code but it did not work.

To be specific:
Let's say my form is /form1 and it can take a list of param...

If I submit /form1?p1=a&p2=b - it comes back with a table (Table1) (queried DB with p1 and p2 params of values a and b)

Now I have a table and when I click on the table row with some value "c" I would like to send query to the same form /form1?p3=c

Now if I do not include p1 and p2 - then /form1 will come back with a result (Table2) - which is expected.

But I would also like to show Table1 in the beginning of the page... NOT JUST Table2. The page should show Table1 and then Table2.

So to include Table1 - I have to send request /form1?p1=a&p2=b&p3=c

So now the /form1 comes back with BOTH Table1 and Table2 resultsets. But it does the execution of query1 "again" to get the result Table1 <-- this is what I do not want. I would like to keep the Table1 result on the page and keep on adding tables (like Table2 or Table3) as we progress with parameters &p3=c or afterwards &p4=d etc. etc.

Hope I could explain it clearly,

(Expected result: should be faster execution of the back-end processing and faster page rendering).

Comment: This is far too broad. What did you try when you used JsonResponse and how did it "not work"?

Comment: When I tried JsonResponse it was still executing the part of the code which was making the first query to DB and get the results of Table1 - that defeats the effort.

Comment: Apologies for being broad - as I would like to get the directions correct before I start walking. Once I know the right approach I can explore and create code but I need that right approach from experts, who had already done this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A rest api seems a little overkill for your use case and would still need something to consume the json data as AJAX would.

to do that :
Create an url taking the parameters you wish to pass.

A view taking those parameters and returning a json response as you wish (easy to test by going directly to the url set)

A javascript to pick up and trigger a lookup on retrieving the json from the url created and populate as required.

```
url:
 url(r'^json_get_info/(?P<parameter3\w+)/$' , views.more_data, name='more_data'),

view:
def more_data(request, parameter3):
    callback = request.GET.get('callback', '')
    data_id=datalist.objects.filter(datalist__exact=parameter3)
    datastore = get_object_or_404(dataStore, pk=data_id)
    qs=[ {"id":dat.id,"value":dat.data_value} for dat in datastore ]
    return JsonResponse(qs,safe=False)

javascript part to read in the json:
$.ajax({
     url: <your address with parameters required>,
     type: "GET",
     dataType: "json",
     cache: false,
     contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",

     success: function(data) {
        $.each( data, function(index,value) {
          data_list_dd.append($("<option />").val(value.id).text(value.data_value));
        });
      },
      error: function(xhr, textStatus) {
        console.log("error..");
      }
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I was thinking of something similar but before trying I wanted to know if REST API is a better approach. Why would you say that REST is a overkill? I would like to know little more details and comparison.

Comment: To implement a REST API requires you to have Get, Put, Post and delete functioning.

Whereas from your description you are just after an ajax query to retrieve a json response.

The former adds more complexity than your use case suggest required.


If the aim is to learn more about implementing REST and its nuances then that is a differing requirement.

Rest really comes into it own when you are looking at differing app inter communicating.

Comment: Thank you @Mark, really appreciate the help.